# Positioning multiple charts using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a chart that queries data from a local database upon change of combobox selection. Works fine. However, I want to add another chart below it. How do I do this?

```
<Grid x:Name="grid" >
   <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
      <TabItem Header="Settings">
         <Grid x:Name="tabItemSettings" Background="#FFE5E5E5">
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
               <DVC:Chart Name="mcChartActivity"  
                          Width="1400" Height="500"  
                          Background="LightBlue"  
                          Foreground="DarkBlue"  
                          Title="Statistics"  >
                  <DVC:Chart.Series>
                     <DVC:ColumnSeries
                        Title="Area Chart"  
                        IndependentValuePath="Key"  
                        DependentValuePath="Value">
                     </DVC:ColumnSeries>
                  </DVC:Chart.Series>
               </DVC:Chart>
            </ScrollViewer>
         </Grid>
      </TabItem>
   </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `RowDefinitions` and set the `Grid.Row` attached property on your controls to indicate in which row they should be displayed. You can also specify a `MinHeight`, `Height` or `MaxHeight` in the `RowDefintion`s. If you want to display the charts in columns, add `ColumnDefintions` instead.

```
<Grid x:Name="grid">
   <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
      <TabItem Header="Settings">
         <Grid x:Name="tabItemSettings" Background="#FFE5E5E5">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition/>
               <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
               <DVC:Chart Name="mcChartActivity"  
                          Width="1400" Height="500"  
                          Background="LightBlue"  
                          Foreground="DarkBlue"  
                          Title="Statistics"  >
                  <DVC:Chart.Series>
                     <DVC:ColumnSeries
                        Title="Area Chart"  
                        IndependentValuePath="Key"  
                        DependentValuePath="Value">
                     </DVC:ColumnSeries>
                  </DVC:Chart.Series>
               </DVC:Chart>
            </ScrollViewer>
            <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
               <!-- ...your other chart. -->
            </ScrollViewer>
         </Grid>
      </TabItem>
   </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Simple but very valuable to me. Thank you.